# What does this R command translate into plain English?

Tags: r

```
mean(mat[2, mat[1, ] == 1] == 1)
```

What does this R command translate into plain English?

According to my understanding:

> 1. take all columns of row#1 where the value is 1. (output is a a row `vector#1`)
> 2. take the columns where `vector#1`==1 of .... .

difficult to read in plain English...

Answer (score 2):

`mat[2,` : second row of mat

`mat[1, ] == 1` : cells of first row of mat where the cell equals 1

`mat[2, mat[1, ] == 1] == 1` : cells of second row of mat equal to 1 where the cells in the first row of mat also have a value equal to 1

Ew!

Comment: so the filtering starts from the external command.

Comment: Work your way from the inside out (nested).